# Accurately Measure the CPU Time Consumption of Flows and Processes (Release Update)

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, process-builder, cpulimit, release-notes

As per Salesforce Summer ’22 Release Notes, Salesforce will be enforcing the update to accurately measure, log, and limit the CPU time consumed by flows and processes. And doc has this point which is confusing for me.

> **Why: Salesforce accurately measures, logs, and limits the CPU time consumed by flows and processes that are configured to run in API
> version 51.0 or later. With this update enabled, the behavior applies
> to all flows and processes, regardless of their run-time API
> versions.**

So, If the `Api Version of a running the flow` is 49.0, will this update accurately measure CPU time or will it not be considered. Part that is confusing me is `regardless of their run-time API versions`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is saying that:

- Without enabling this feature, API 51+ flows are accurately measured while API 50- flows are not.
- Enabling this feature means all flows are accurately measured regardless of API version.

Same for processes from the process builder.

This allows for backward compatibility. Where you have a flow that works with the approximate measurements that were applied, it can continue to function exactly the same as long as this feature is off. You may find turning this on causes a flow to fail in some cases where it did not previously so you may need to change it.